# C++ passing a class pointer to another class by constructor

Tags: c++, oop

I have the following situation

`cpp` file:

```
#include <Player.h>
Ball::Ball(GLint x, GLint y, Player* bottomPlayer, Player* topPlayer)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

header file:

```
class Ball
{
    public:
        Ball(GLint x, GLint y, Player* bottomPlayer, Player* topPlayer);
    private:
        Player* bottomPlayer, topPlayer;
}
```

Another `cpp` file:

```
#include "Player.h"
Player::Player(GLint windowWidth, GLint windowHeight, GLint playerLength)
{
  // initialization
}
```

and I am getting the following error:

> no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'

I have no idea what this error means... Why is it thinking that my constructor is a function or something like that...

Comment: That error means that a default constructor of `Player` is needed to be called in your code somewhere, but you didn't provided one. Impossible to tell how to fix that unless you post a [MCVE].

Comment: None of this code invokes the `Player` constructor. All `Player` code references are pointers only. The problem is related to what you chose *not* to post (which my crystal ball says is a member variable in class `Ball`  (or somewhere else) of type `Player` that is not properly being constructed with the only constructor you've provided (three arguments)). That error message should have come with a line number where it takes place.

Comment: @WhozCraig it point to the `Ball`'s constructor

Comment: `Player* bottomPlayer, topPlayer; ` - Um. `topPlayer` isn't a pointer; it's an instance. It's missing the `*` before the variable. And that, kids, is why we don't put multiple pointer variables on the same decl line.

Comment: @WhozCraig yup that was the problem... anyway I didn't quite get that ... I thought that the `Player *` will be for both `bottomPlayer ` and `topPlayer`, Like the compiler will do something like `Player * bottomPlayer;` `Player * topPlayer;`

Comment: Nope. It's a common error for beginners. The asterisk is married to the variable; not the type (but can be married the type via alias, which you should *never* do; it just makes the code harder to read). Ideally, you have `Player *bottomPlayer; Player *topPlayer;` on separate lines.

Comment: @WhozCraig Anyway still no idea why I was getting the wrong error. If u can make an answer so I can vote up

Comment: You were not getting the wrong error.  You were getting the correct error.

Comment: That error was the correct error for the code youhad. You were getting that error because `topPlayer`, as an instance member of `Ball`, needs to construct before entering the body of `Ball::Ball`. But it can't because there is no `Player::Player()`. There is only `Player::Player(GLint, GLint, GLint)`, and you didn't member-intiialize `topPlayer` with that constructor (or any other). Without specified initialization the compiler tried to use the default no-arg constructor, but there isn't one, plain and simple.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't quite get what you mean by instance member. The member initializers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it thinking that my constructor is a function or something like that...

Because constructors are functions.

> I have no idea what this error means...

It means that you've attempted to default construct an instance of class `Player` despite the fact that the class is not default constructible. A class is not default constructible, if it has no default constructor i.e. it has no constructor that can be called without arguments.

To fix it either:

- Don't default construct `Player`
- Define a default constructor for `Player`

> ```
> private:
>     Player* bottomPlayer, topPlayer;
> ```

This declares a player pointer `bottomPlayer` and a player instance (not a pointer) `topPlayer`. Since you don't initialise `topPlayer` explicitly in the member initialisation list, you default initialise the member. This causes the error.